# Javascript regex to replace the continue string not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the string which start with`@`, for some of the string it is working fine but for the some string it is not working.

```js
var xaf = "@Test user has @some @data to @replace @mkh it is replaced";

var rpObj = {Test:"NEWVALUE",some:"OTHERNEWVALUE",data:"NEWDATA",replace:"RP STR", mkh:"NEW DDAATTAA"};

var reg = /(@(\w+)\b)/g;

var result;

while ((result = reg.exec(xaf)) !== null) {
  xaf = xaf.replace(new RegExp("@"+result[2] + "\\b", 'ig'), rpObj[result[2]]);
}
console.log(xaf)
```

and result is `NEWVALUE user has OTHERNEWVALUE NEWDATA to RP STR @mkh it is replaced`

I am not sure why `@mkh` it is not replaced with the the new value.. I tried adding and removing word boundary but nothing helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a callback function as the replacement argument:

```js
var xaf = "@Test user has @some @data to @replace @mkh it is replaced @ttt";

var rpObj = {Test:"NEWVALUE",some:"OTHERNEWVALUE",data:"NEWDATA",replace:"RP STR", mkh:"NEW DDAATTAA"};

var reg = /@(\w+)/g;

xaf = xaf.replace(reg, (m,g)=>rpObj[g] ?? m);

console.log(xaf)
```

Note this will replace each `@(\w+)` match once it is found, inline. You need no word boundry, there is an implicit word boundary after `\w+`.

Also, `\w` matches lower- and uppercase letters, no need using the `i` flag.

To avoid replacing missing `rpObj` keys with `undefined`, you need to use

```js
xaf = xaf.replace(reg, (m,g)=>rpObj[g] ?? m);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to this and use white space character instead of boundary

```
var xaf = "@Test user has @some @data to @replace @mkh it is replaced";
var reg = /@\w+(\s+|$)/g;
xaf = xaf.replace(reg, 'ZZZ$1')
```

Comment: I have updated my question.. And `$` matches the end of the string it won't behave like word boundary.